# How to end the loop when I type n?

Tags: python, input

```
import random

#yes or no
yrn = input("R u going to play black jack? (Y/N): ").upper()
if yrn == "Y":
    player1 = random.randint(1,19)
    player2 = random.randint(1,19)
    print(player1,player2)

    while True:
        player1_yrn = input("Player 1, Do you want more numbers? (Y/N): ").upper()
        if player1_yrn == "Y":
            player1 = player1 + random.randint(1,19)
            print(f"Player 1's number is {player1}")
        else:
            print(f"Player 1's number is {player1}")
            quit()


        player2_yrn = input("Player 2, Do you want more numbers? (Y/N) : ").upper()
        if player2_yrn == "Y":
            player2 = player2 + random.randint(1,19)
            print(f"Player 2's number is {player2}")
        else:
            print(f"Player 2's number is {player2}")
```

What I want is when I press 'n', the asking loop needs to end only for that player.
For example: When I press 'n' for the question: "Player 2, Do you want more numbers? (Y/N) : ", then the asking loop ends only for player 2 and the program only asks for player 1 for more numbers.

Comment: You need to remember that the player said "no more cards" somehow

Comment: A boolean flag perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You need some state to allow you to remember when a player says "no more cards". A boolean flag per player would be one way to do it:

```
player1_keep_dealing = True
player2_keep_dealing = True
while player1_keep_dealing and player2_keep_dealing:
    if player1_keep_dealing:
        player1_yrn = input("Player 1, Do you want more numbers? (Y/N): ").upper()
        if player1_yrn == "Y":
            player1 = player1 + random.randint(1,19)
            print(f"Player 1's number is {player1}")
        else:
            print(f"Player 1's number is {player1}")
            player1_keep_dealing = False

    if player2_keep_dealing:
        player2_yrn = input("Player 2, Do you want more numbers? (Y/N) : ").upper()
        if player2_yrn == "Y":
            player2 = player2 + random.randint(1,19)
            print(f"Player 2's number is {player2}")
        else:
            print(f"Player 2's number is {player2}")
            player2_keep_dealing = False
```

Notice that you now have a natural loop termination condition.

**Design Note**

If you have a bunch of repeated variables with numbers in the names, and may want to add more, it may be time to look at classes. For example, player state and functionality can reasonably be encapsulated in a `Player` class:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n = n
        keep_dealing = True
        self.value = random.randint(1, 19)

    def ask(self):
        yrn = input(f"Player {self.n}, Do you want more numbers? (Y/N): ").upper()
        if yrn == "Y":
            self.value += random.randint(1, 19)
        else:
            self.keep_dealing = False
        print(f"Player {self.n}'s number is {self.value}")
```

In your loop, you can

Answer (score 0):

Make a set storing which players are still actively playing (being dealt to). You can also store their scores / numbers in a dictionary for convenience and avoiding duplication.

```
playing = {1, 2}
numbers = {1: random.randint(1,19), 2: random.randint(1, 19)}
print(*numbers.values())
while playing:
    for player in list(playing):  # we make a copy of the active players to iterate over
        more = input(f"Player {player}, Do you want more numbers? (Y/N): ").upper()
        if more == "Y":
            numbers[player] += random.randint(1,19)
        else:
            playing.remove(player) # stop dealing to this player
        print(f"Player {player}'s number is {numbers[player]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way would be to keep track of which player is still playing with booleans, and execute the request code only if the player is still playing.
Also, you could use a list to store players scores, and a list to store which player is still playing, which would lead to something like this :

```
players = []
yrn = input("R u going to play black jack? (Y/N): ").upper()
if yrn == "Y":
    player_number = int(input("how many players ?"))
    for player in range(player_number):
        players.append((random.randint(1,19), True))

while True:
    for i,player in enumerate(players):
        if not player[1]:
            continue
    player_yrn = input(f"Player {i}, Do you want more numbers? (Y/N): ").upper()
    if player_yrn == "Y":
        player[0] = player[0] + random.randint(1,19)
    else:
        player[1] = False
    print(f"Player {i}'s number is {player1}")
```

Such code would be much more modular :)